# Code First EF5: One-to-Zero-or-One relationship is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

None of the similair questions seem to be able to solve this problem. I'm using Entity Framework 5, MVC 4, .NET 4.5 for my web app, designed with VS 2012.

I have 2 classes that are supposed to be in a parent-child relationship.

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    // Other stuff

    public int? JoggerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Jogger Jogger{ get; set; }
}
```

and

```
 public class Jogger
{
    [Key]
    public int JoggerId { get; set; }

    [Required, ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

With Fluent API:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.Jogger)
            .WithRequired(c => c.UserProfile)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

A User can be a Jogger but can also not be a Jogger i.e. one User to zero or one Jogger. the relationship looks fine on the EF Powertools edmx view but I cannot get the Foreign key to work with the UserProfile UserId.

Is my Fluent API wrong or is it my models? Please help - I am truly stuck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mapping with Fluent API is OK, but remove the `UserProfile.JoggerId` and the `Jogger.UserId` properties from your model and it should work. The reason is that Entity Framework uses the primary key of `Jogger` as the foreign key to `UserProfile`, so you don't need to (and can't) have a separate foreign key property. This kind of one-to-one relationship is called "[Shared Primary Key Association](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/04/14/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations.aspx)".

**Edit**

Keep in mind that the primary key of `Jogger` (as the dependent of the relationship) is **not** autogenerated in the database, only the primary key of `UserProfile` is autogenerated (as the principal of the relationship).

The way how you would insert a `UserProfile` or a `Jogger` or both into the database is the following:

- If you want to insert a `UserProfile` without a `Jogger` just add it to the context:

  ```
  using (var context = new MyContext())
  {
      var newUserProfile = new UserProfile();
      // no key needs to be supplied, the DB will take care

      context.UserProfiles.Add(newUserProfile);
      context.SaveChanges();
  }
  ```
- If you want to insert a `UserProfile` with a `Jogger` in a single step:

  ```
  using (var context = new MyContext())
  {
      var newUserProfile = new UserProfile { Jogger = new Jogger() };
      // no key needs to be supplied, neither for UserProfile
      // nor for Jogger, the DB will take care

      context.UserProfiles.Add(newUserProfile);
      context.SaveChanges();
  }
  ```
- If you want to insert a `Jogger` (and it must be a `Jogger` for an existing `UserProfile`):

  ```
  using (var context = new MyContext())
  {
      var newJogger = new Jogger { JoggerId = someExistingUserProfileId };
      // a valid key needs to be supplied, otherwise you would violate a FK
      // constraint in the database

      context.Joggers.Add(newJogger);
      context.SaveChanges();
  }
  ```

**Edit 2**

For your use case where you don't have the `UserId` directly available but the `Name` (as authenticated user) instead you must load the key or the `UserProfile` first from the database:

```
// we are in an ASP.NET MVC controller action here
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    string userName = User.Identity.Name;
    int? userId = context.UserProfiles
        .Where(u => u.Name == userName)
        .Select(u => (int?)u.UserId)
        .SingleOrDefault();

    if (userId.HasValue)
    {
        var newJogger = new Jogger { JoggerId = userId.Value };
        context.Joggers.Add(newJogger);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Or loading the `UserProfile` will work as well:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    string userName = User.Identity.Name;
    UserProfile userProfile = context.UserProfiles
        .Where(u => u.Name == userName)
        .SingleOrDefault();

    if (userProfile != null)
    {
        userProfile.Jogger = new Jogger();
        // I believe you don't need to set the JoggerId key now,
        // I'm not sure though

        context.SaveChanges();
        // Change tracking recognizes the new Jogger
        // no context.Joggers.Add is required
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Slauma. I tried this and the id's were resolved but then got the same sort of error where the id values are not updating. 'The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "UserProfile_Jogger". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-20130725111018", table "dbo.UserProfile", column 'UserId'.
The statement has been terminated.'   When I add a user its perfect but when I add the Jogger profile it breaks. Appreciate the assist. Springbokkie

Comment: @Springbokkie: `Jogger` is the entity that is dependent on `UserProfile`. When you add a `Jogger` you must set its key property `JoggerId` to a valid existing `UserProfile` key. The `JoggerId` is not a database generated key, so you must supply the value manually.

Comment: Thanks. Do I modify the Jogger class e.g. JoggerId {get; set{ = UserProfile.UserId};} or do I set that in the Controller Method for Create? If its set in the class please show me what code to use. Sorry - I really am new to all of this.

Comment: @Springbokkie: Don't modify the class, just set the key outside (in controller for example). I have added a few examples to my answer, see the Edit section.

Comment: I would mark up the answer but I'm short 2 rep. Thanks for your time and patience. you rock!

Comment: My main problem is the declaration of the someExistingUserProfileId. The User is logged in to access the Create Jogger method so there is a valid UserId, but how do I declare it in the last example?

Comment: @Springbokkie: In an ASP.NET MVC controller action you can access the name of the authenticated user with `User.Identity.Name`. But that's a `string` (usually the name the user entered on the login page). Your `UserId` is an `int`. Are the names unique, i.e. every user name has a unique `UserId` in the database?

Comment: @Springbokkie: See Edit 2.